# React loop through json object and display data

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-read-json?file=index.tsx)

I have a simple json file that I'm importing and I would like to loop through and output the json data in a div

I'll probable want to pick out parts of the json but for now I just need to be able to output the json

Do I need to create an array from the json data and then map over that.

```
const showProductData = Object.keys(ProductData).map(function(key) {
  return <div>{ProductData[key]}</div>;
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>JSON</h2>
      {showProductData}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: have you tried your code? it looks mostly right to me. on a separate note, you can also iterate over object values: `Object.values(data).map(d => <div>{d}</div>)` or object entries: `Object.entries(data).map([key, value] => ())` - also, you will probably have to give the div in the map function a key prop https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message, Objects are not valid as a React Child. To modify your current code to just show the json, you will need to convert the object into a string.

```js
const showProductData = Object.keys(ProductData).map(function(key) {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(ProductData[key])}</div>;
});
```

To be more concise with what we're accessing, we can instead use `Object.values()` instead:

```js
const showProductData = Object.values(ProductData).map(function(value) {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(value)}</div>;
});
```

To further access specific points of the data, you can use dot notation to access primitive values:

```js
const showProductData = Object.values(ProductData).map(function(value) {
  return <div>Weight: {value.ProductWeight}</div>;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well, when i show ur a question, immediately i thought 'recursive solution' :)
so basically this is the code, I tried to explain it, feel free to dig into it

```
function getAllProps(obj) {
  let value = obj;

  // in case it is an object / array, which true, at any json file, at least at the beginning
  if (typeof obj === "object") {
    value = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
      // and then check again if the value of the 'key' is an object
      // because we cant just out put object in react
      if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
        // then out put the key name (property, 'ProductOne' for example)
        // and call the function again since we know it is an object.
        // basiclly the function will call it self again and again
        // until the value will be different than 'object'
        return (
          <div key={key}>
            <div style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
              <strong> {key} </strong>
              {getAllProps(obj[key])}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }

      return (
        <div key={key} style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
          {key}: {obj[key]}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  return value;
}

const products = getAllProps(ProductData);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>JSON</h2>
      {products}
    </div>
  );
};
```

actually, just check that [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-read-json-mphacy?file=index.tsx)

read the comments, try to understand my 'recursive solution'